Строковой калькулятор, проблема с операциями при сложение строк (java)
Подскажите пожалуйста при вводе строки с помощью Scanner к примеру "Привет/" + "мир" я получаю следующую ошибку:
Введите любую строку:  "Привет/" + "мир"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at CalculatorString.calculateStringResult(CalculatorString.java:42)
at CalculatorString.main(CalculatorString.java:10)
Process finished with exit code 1
Проблема в том, что я складываю две строки массива, разделение должен быть по " + ", а получил разделение по / который стоит после слова Привет -> "Привет/".
Как лучше исправить эту проблему? Изменить во всех кейсах разделитель? Или можно как то игнорировать каким-то методом лишние знаки +, -, / и * которые могут попасть в первую или вторую строку над которыми нужно провести операцию.
Буду благодарен за совет по улучшению кода!

public class CalculatorString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите любую строку: ");
        String string = scanner.nextLine();
        string = string.replace("\"", "").trim();
        try {
            System.out.println(calculateStringResult(string));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Нельзя число делить и умножать на строку!");
        }
    }

    public static String calculateStringResult(String stringResult) throws NumberFormatException{
        StringBuilder modifiedStr = new StringBuilder();
        char symbol;
        char firstSymbol;
        char lastSymbol;
        String[] arrString;
        int elementsArrString;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringResult.length(); i++) {
            symbol = stringResult.charAt(i);
            firstSymbol = stringResult.charAt(0);
            lastSymbol = stringResult.charAt(stringResult.length() - 1);

            switch (symbol) {
                case '+':
                    arrString = stringResult.trim().split(" \\+ ");
                    if (arrString[0].length() > 10 || arrString[1].length() > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Одна из строк превышает допустимую длинну 10 символов");
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(firstSymbol) || Character.isDigit(lastSymbol)) {
                        System.err.println("Первый или последний аргумент не должен быть числом!");
                    } else {
                        modifiedStr.append(arrString[0].concat(arrString[1])).insert(0, "\"").insert(modifiedStr.length(), "\"");
                    }
                    break;
                case '/':
                    arrString = stringResult.trim().split(" / ");
                    elementsArrString = Integer.parseInt(arrString[1]);
                    if (arrString[0].length() > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Одна из строк превышает допустимую длинну 10 символов");
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(firstSymbol)) {
                        System.err.println("Первый аргумент не должен быть числом!");
                    } else if (elementsArrString < 0 || elementsArrString > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Число должно быть от 1 до 10");
                    } else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < arrString[0].length() / elementsArrString; j++) {
                            symbol = arrString[0].charAt(j);
                            modifiedStr.append(symbol);
                        }
                        modifiedStr.insert(0, "\"").insert(modifiedStr.length(), "\"");
                    }
                    break;
                case '*':
                    arrString = stringResult.trim().split(" \\* ");
                    elementsArrString = Integer.parseInt(arrString[1]);

                    if (arrString[0].length() > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Одна из строк превышает допустимую длинну 10 символов");
                    } else if (elementsArrString < 0 || elementsArrString > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Число должно быть от 1 до 10");
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(firstSymbol) || !Character.isDigit(lastSymbol)) {
                        System.err.println("Первый аргумент не должен быть числом!");
                    } else {
                        modifiedStr = new StringBuilder(elementsArrString * arrString[0].length());
                        modifiedStr.append(arrString[0].repeat(elementsArrString)).insert(0, "\"").insert(modifiedStr.length(), "\"");
                    }
                    break;
                case '-':
                    arrString = stringResult.trim().split(" - ");
                    elementsArrString = arrString[0].indexOf(arrString[1]);
                    if (arrString[0].length() > 10 || arrString[1].length() > 10) {
                        System.err.println("Одна из строк превышает допустимую длинну 10 символов");
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(firstSymbol) || Character.isDigit(lastSymbol)) {
                        System.err.println("Оба аргумента должны быть строками!");
                    } else {
                        if (elementsArrString == -1) {
                            modifiedStr.append(arrString[0]);
                        } else {
                            String oneStrMinusSecondStr = arrString[0].substring(0, elementsArrString);
                            oneStrMinusSecondStr += arrString[0].substring(elementsArrString + arrString[1].length());
                            modifiedStr.append(oneStrMinusSecondStr).insert(0, "\"").insert(modifiedStr.length(), "\"");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (modifiedStr.length() > 40) {
            String endStr = "..." + "\"";
            return modifiedStr.insert(0, "\"").substring(0, 40).concat(endStr);
        } else {
            return modifiedStr.toString().trim();
        }
    }
}```


как задать хороший вопрос

@GansGremory, Объясните, для начала что должен делать ваш "калькулятор", какие операции над какими операндами должны выполняться, потому что логика очень странная.  Что касается основной проблемы, похоже, что вы хотите игнорировать разделители (символы операций), которые попадают внутрь "строк", заключённых в двойные кавычки, так?  В любом случае вам придётся писать парсер для своей грамматики, который преобразует входную строку в пару операндов и операцию, после чего вы проверите, корректны ли операнды, и затем отдельно реализуете логику "калькулятора" в зависимости от операции.

Да все верно, знаки и цифры попадающие в строки в кавычках должны игнорироваться,  проблему уже решил, попробую воспользоваться вашим решением. С точки зрения грамматики написания кода, буду благодарен если дадите советы, какими бы они критичными не были, я только изучаю java и мне не помешали бы советы относительно кода.

Добавить
case '"': 
    i++;
    while(stringResult.charAt(i) !='"' && i < stringResult.length()) {i++;}
    break;

но в целом все написано неправильно. Подробнее раскажут в Code Review.
